# How to change Aptana3 html template？？

Tags: aptana, aptana3

learning js by using aptana,

aptana2 can initial html file content in "Windows - Preferences - Aptana - HTML"

But in aptana3 i couldn't find this setting.

so i add new html file in project explorer by rightclick menu "new from template - html - xhtml 1.0 transitional template"

now the problem is...how to change template initial content？

Answer (score 0):

Please see instructions for [Creating a New Template](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+template) and [Modifying an Existing Template](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+an+existing+template).